# pagespeed insights error "Oops! Something went wrong. generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1"

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

the following error showing while checking my website

Oops! Something went wrong.
generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

could not find the solution on my side